# Create a regex from a blacklist and whitelist regex expressions to identify and remove url parameters

Tags: java, regex

I would like to identify and remove some parameters from a Url using a blacklist and whitelist. However, I would like to use regular expressions on the blacklist/whitelist and not a list of words. Every match on the blacklist regex will be removed except if the whitelist regex can allow.

This regex will be used on the `replaceAll` String method on Java. I almost found the solution, but I'm having some troubles to make work on general cases.

For example, if I have the list configured with the regular expressions:

- whitelist: `(param1)`
- blacklist: `(param1|param2)`

The objective: remove `param2` and not `param1`, because `param1` is in the whitelist regex.

I create an expression putting the whitelist on the negative lookahead:

```
(?!(param1))(param1|param2)
```

And combine this expression with another regular expression to identify the Url query string delimiters:

```
(?<=[?&;])(?!(param1))(param1|param2)=.*?($|[&;])
```

The [result](https://regex101.com/r/gnNmVD/1) is that only matches the param2:

```
https://www.so.com?param2=2&param1=1
https://www.so.com?param1=1
https://www.so.com?param1=1&param2=2
https://www.so.com?param3=3&param1=1&param2=2
https://www.so.com?param3=3&param2=2&param1=1
```

The Java code is something like:

```
url.replaceAll("(?<=[?&;])" + asNegativeLookahead(whitelist, blacklist) + "=.*?($|[&;])", "")
   .replaceAll("[?&;]$", "");
```

So far, so good.

But the **problem** happens when I used some more general regular expression on the blacklist, like `.*`:

- whitelist: `(param1)`
- blacklist: .*

This makes [matches everything](https://regex101.com/r/gnNmVD/3) after the param1 when the first argument is param1, ignoring the whitelist regex.

I found a solution identifying each parameter with another regular expression and matching each group with whitelist and blacklist, but I'm not really confident about this code, because I need to manually recreate the Url with the parameters and still need to use negative lookahead, not really simplifying the solution.

Comment: I think this part is not going to match param1 because the assertion states that what is on the right is not param1 `(?<=[?&;])(?!(param1))(param1|param2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use this combination pattern:

```
([?&](?!.*&)|(?<=[?&;]))(?!(param1))(?=(param1|param2))([^&;=\n\r]*)=.*?($|[&;])

                whitelist ◄└──────┘    └─────────────┘► blacklist
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ESDPl0/2).